# Find the number of pairs i and j such that the product of A[i] and A[j] divides K efficiently

Tags: c++, product, division, number-theory

Suppose there is list of integers in an array A. 
Given another array Q containing queries. 
For each query K you need to find the number of pairs i and j such that the product of A[i] and A[j] divides K.

**How can this be done efficiently without any brute-force method?**

For example :

Given 
A : 2 5 6 2 3 
Q : 12 7 100 200 
Output : 5 0 2 3

Explanation : 

Number of pairs that divide 12 are : (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (3,4), (4,5) 
Number of pairs that divide 7 are : None (0) and so on...

**How can this be done efficiently without any brute-force method?**

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?  Did you try factoring?  How big are the numbers and list?  Simply printing out the list of pairs is O(n^2).  How fast is fast enough?

Comment: link to the oriiginal prblem : https://www.codechef.com/NPLQ1601/problems/NPLELD

I got tle

Comment: @MoinakDebnath: Time Limit Exceeded? So you do have running code which is just too slow?

Answer (score 2):

Prime factor everything down to powers of primes.

For each query value, build N dimensional array, where N is the prime factors of the query value.  Each dimension has k+1 entries, where k is the power of the corresponding prime.

Plot each potential factor in this array, incrementing its location by 1.  If outside of array, discard.

Use n dimensional scan to store the cdf in each dimension along each dimension.  There are less than 40 entries total, so this should be fast enough.

Sum "inverse" location of each potential factor.  If I_j and I_j is not valid, check for it manually by doubling prime powers and subtract one.

You could pre-factor every target or each source, and build one huge array.  But that is probably too far.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick shoot like that:

You can »precompile« a list `S` of the results of all possible `A[i] * A[j]` and filter that list for doubles like that;

```
A = [1,2,3];
Q = [3,4,5]

All possible results:

1 * [2,3] => 2,3
2 * [1,3] => 2,6
3 * [1,2] => 3,6 //these are 6 values to test for each

S = [2,3,6] //here are only three unique

Than:

2/2, 2/3, 2/6 => 1
3/2, 3/3, 3/6 => 1
6/2, 6/3, 6/6 => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A will probably do:

1. Create a hash map, *H* that contains the of product all *A[i]* and *A[j]* multiples from set *A*. (If you prefer, you may use a 2D array instead).
2. Let a zero initialized *m* be the number of pairs in *K*. Then for each factors of *K*, find it in *H*. If its there, then increase *m* by `1`.

> Running time: `O(N * N) + c * Q`. Where *N* is size of the array *A*;
>   *c* is average number of factors of query the values; `Q` is number of queries.

In C++:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

//returns a hashmap, containing all allowed pairs in vec
std::unordered_map<int, int> build_lookup_table(const std::vector<int>& vec){
    std::unordered_map<int, int> table(vec.size());
    for(std::size_t row = 0; row < vec.size(); row++)
        for(std::size_t col = row + 1; col < vec.size(); col++)
            ++table[vec[row] * vec[col]];
    return table;
}

//a fairly fast and simple way to quickly get factors without using % modulus
std::vector<int> get_factors(const int k){
    std::vector<int> vec;
    const int limit = std::sqrt(k);
    for(int i = 1; i <= limit; i++){
        int val = k / i;
        if(val * i == k)
            vec.push_back(i), vec.push_back(val);
    }
    if(limit * limit == k)      //if its a perfect square
        vec.pop_back();
    return vec;
}


int main(){
    std::vector<int> A{ 2, 5, 6, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> Q{12, 20, 7, 10, 200 };
    std::vector<int> ans(Q.size());

    const auto lookup_table = build_lookup_table(A);
    for(auto k : Q){
        auto pairs = 0;
        for(auto factor : get_factors(k)){
            auto iter = lookup_table.find(factor);
            pairs += iter != lookup_table.end() ? iter->second : 0;
        }
        ans.push_back(pairs);
    }

    for(auto x : ans)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[See a Demo](http://ideone.com/tf7x6l)

Comment: still got tle with thsi approach , can there be any more optimaztions possible  :/
@WhiZTiM 
link to the problm : [linkto problem] https://www.codechef.com/problems/NPLELD

my solution : [my solution]http://ideone.com/dxNVav